# Can java.util.regex.Pattern do partial matches?

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to know if a stream/string contains an input that **could** match a regular expression.

For example

```
 String input="AA";
 Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("AAAAAB");
 Matcher matcher=pat.matcher(input);
 //<-- something here returning true ?
```

or

```
 String input="BB";
 Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("AAAAAB");
 Matcher matcher=pat.matcher(input);
 //<-- something here returning false ?
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not really how regex's work. The pattern should be a substring of the input, or there's no match. You could write your own thing that does the same, but it would be like a reverse regex. 

If you reverse your 'input' and 'pattern' strings, then call matcher.matches(input) - you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Java provides a way to do that.  First you have to call one of the standard methods to apply the regex, like `matches()` or `find()`.  If that returns `false`, you can use the `hitEnd()` method to find out if some longer string could have matched:

```
String[] inputs = { "AA", "BB" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("AAAAAB");
Matcher m = p.matcher("");
for (String s : inputs)
{
  m.reset(s);
  System.out.printf("%s -- full match: %B; partial match: %B%n",
                    s, m.matches(), m.hitEnd());
}
```

output:

```
AA -- full match: FALSE; partial match: TRUE
BB -- full match: FALSE; partial match: FALSE
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you are in luck: Java's regex does have the method you want:

[`public boolean hitEnd()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd())

> Returns true if the end of input was hit by the search engine in the last match operation performed by this matcher.
>
> When this method returns true, then it is possible that more input would have changed the result of the last search.

So in your case:

```
String input="AA";
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("AAB");
Matcher matcher=pat.matcher(input);
System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // prints "false"
System.out.println(matcher.hitEnd());  // prints "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to hitEnd is to specify the requirement in the RE itself.

```
// Accepts up to 5 'A's or 5 'A's and a 'B' (and anything following)
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^(?:A{1,5}$|A{5}B)");
boolean yes = pat.matcher("AA").find();
boolean no = pat.matcher("BB").find();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [Matcher.matches()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) not do what you want ?

Comment: He wants the reverse.  His pattern is the longer string, he wants to find out of the input matches *so far*.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to check if a string contains some pattern specified by a regex:

```
String s = ...;
s.matches( regex )
```