# Day names or first 3 characters

Tags: python, regex

I want my regex to catch:

```
monday mon thursday thu ...
```

So it's possible to write something like this:

```
(?P<day>monday|mon|thursday|thu ...
```

But I guess that there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `mon(day)?|tue(sday)?|wed(nesday)?`, etc.

The `?` is "zero-or-one repetition of"; so it's sort of "optional".

If you don't need all the suffix captures, you can use the `(?:___)` non-capturing groups, so:

`mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?`

You can group Monday/Friday/Sunday together if you wish:

`(?:mon|fri|sun)(?:day)?`

I'm not sure if that's more readable, though.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### Another option

Java's [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) lets you test if there's a partial match. If Python does too, then you can use that and see if at least (or perhaps exactly) 3 characters matched on `monday|tuesday|....` (i.e. all complete names).

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class PartialMatch {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] tests = {
         "sunday", "sundae", "su", "mon", "mondayyyy", "frida"
      };
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:sun|mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur)day");
      for (String test : tests) {
         Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
         System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", test, 
            m.matches() ? "Exact match!" :
            m.hitEnd() ? "Partial match of " + test.length():
            "No match!"
         );
      }
   }
}
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/IYduH)):

```
sunday = Exact match!
sundae = No match!
su = Partial match of 2
mon = Partial match of 3
mondayyyy = No match!
frida = Partial match of 5
```

#### Related questions

- [Can java.util.regex.Pattern do partial matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526756/can-java-util-regex-pattern-do-partial-matches)
- [How can I perform a partial match with java.util.regex.*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469231/how-can-i-perform-a-partial-match-with-java-util-regex)