# Can regcomp/regexec/regfree do partial matches?

Tags: c, regex, partial

This is the '**C**' version of my previous old+java question [Can java.util.regex.Pattern do partial matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526756/can-java-util-regex-pattern-do-partial-matches)

Is it possible to know if a string contains an input that **could** match a regular expression using the [regcomp/regexec/regfree library](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html).

e.g:

```
 input : "AA";
 regex : "AAAAAB";
 //<-- regexec returns true ?
```

and

```
 input : "BB";
 regex : "AAAAAB";
 //<-- regexec returns false ?
```

Comment: Looks like there is no support for this. In Boost for C++, there is a partial_match though: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/partial_matches.html

Comment: @Pierre Probably should MCVE. Not sure if you mean the regex examples to be bound ^RE$ or not. I would write the regex pattern to be matched as (_assuming bound as ^AAAAAB$_) `"^(A{1,5})?(B?)$"`. That is to say an optional string of 1 to 5 A's, followed by an optional B. A single `A` would match, as would a single `B`. `AB` would also match, as well as 2-5 A's. Unfortunately the empty string would also match in my example.