# java pattern matches not working

Tags: java, regex

i want to get class name from a string .for example `public class hello extends jframe` .then i want to get `hello` as class name .but if String is `public class hello` and also i want to get `hello`.

i write a regex and it's work fine . [see here online preview](http://regexr.com/3bgmk) .

this is my regex

```
(public)*\s*class\s+(\S+)\s+
```

preview

[image]

as you can see it works ..it capture class names . (red color -> group 2)

but in java `m.matches()` returns false  because whole string doesn't match but a part .so according to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2526985/2227526) , i used `hitEnd()` method but it doesn't work either ?? how can i capture class name when even string exactly doesn't match but partially

```
String cstring = "public class hello extends jframe ";
Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("(public)*\\s*class\\s+(\\S+)\\s*");
Matcher m = classPattern.matcher(cstring);
m.matches();
if (m.hitEnd()) {
    System.out.println("found");
    String className = m.group(2);
    System.out.println(className);
}
```

output is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `find()` to make the engine find its match before trying to access it.

```
String s  = "public class hello extends jframe";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("public\\s*class\\s+(\\S+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("found");
    String className = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(className);
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/IetKBn)

Comment: so shouldn't i use `hitEnd` because String doesn't matches exactly but partially with the pattern

Comment: @whiletrue, No you shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

See comments in the code and explanation below:

```
String cstring = "public class hello extends jframe ";
Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?class\\s+(\\S+)\\s*"); // regex was changed a bit
Matcher m = classPattern.matcher(cstring);
//m.matches();  // <-- no need for that 
if (m.find()) { // use find() instead of m.hitEnd()
    System.out.println("found");
    String className = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(className);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
found
hello
```

Basically I removed the `(public)` from the regex and used the "1" matched group (zero is the whole expression in case there is a match). Your regex could be used as well, but then you'll have to use the seconded matched group as `(public)` will be come the first.

In addition to that I removed `m.matches()` which is not needed and replaced the `m.hitEnd()` with `m.find()` which should be used to iterate the matched results.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if (m.find())`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String cstring = "public class hello extends jframe ";
    Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("(public)*\\s*class\\s+(\\S+)\\s*");
    Matcher m = classPattern.matcher(cstring);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("found");
        String className = m.group(2);
        System.out.println(className);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
found
hello
```

Also, your capture group `(\\S+)` will match any non-whitespace character which can result in invalid class names.  Consider changing that capture group to `([a-zA-Z_$]\\w*)` to capture valid class names.